# What will happen to Xamarin now with the arrival of Visual Studio in MAC? is the end of Xamarin as a standalone tool?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I want to install Xamarin in my new MAC, but now with the arrival of Visual Studio to MAC, it seems Visual Studio contains Xamarin... my question is: Will Xamarin Disappear with the arrival of Visual Studio in MAC? what do you recommend to install Xamarin or Visual Studio for MAC?

Comment: VS4M is the "next version" of Xamarin Studio, version 7 in terms of git tags/braches/addins/... Same original code base: MonoDevelop -> Xamarin Studio -> Visual Studio For Mac but a rebranding and with additional features. The Windows version of Xamarin Studio is sunsetted as Visual Studio Community with the Xamarin addin taking its place.

Comment: Yeah, I think that Microsoft bought Xamarin ?

Comment: It is very interesting that you did not pay much attention to what happened after the acquisition,

http://corefx.strikingly.com

Xamarin team is the ones behind Visual Studio for Mac, and all Visual Studio for Mac sessions at conferences like Build 2017 are hosted by the original Xamarin guys.

Comment: Xamarin was acquired by Microsoft in March 2016.  Exactly what will happen in the future is speculation that nobody on SO can answer for you.